# How to open the door in secret passage to kill Battle Beta in Winding Road?

Tags: geneforge-1

There is a door that I am trying to open in in Winding Road map where serviles send you to kill battle beta, how do I open it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a lever behind a tree, near the wall a bit to the north near the wall.

It can be seen in the screenshot below.

[image]